# Google Play Games Services not able to login - returns Canceled

Tags: android, coronasdk, google-play-games

I'm using Corona SDK and trying to add Google Services to my game and followed the tutorial [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/tutorial/games/gameLeaderboards/index.html#collecting-information) but the sign-in fails. I've tried debugging with Android Studio and logcat and noticed that gpgsInitListener throws the following as soon as the login starts:

```
event.isError: {
      isError = true,
      name = "login",
      phase = "canceled"
    }
```

Funny thing is that I never have the opportunity to choose which account to use (I think other apps show which email is being used and ask to continue). After I access the scene containing the code, I see a "Google Play Games" popup and then a spinning wheel followed by a black screen.

My code is exactly the same as in the tutorial, except for the packageName, appID and leaderboardID. I've signed the app with Corona and then uploaded the APK to the Google console (so the SHA1 fingerprint should be correct). My app and game are published in the internal test status and I have added my email to the list of testers.

In the logcat I see the following messages:

```
2019-09-05 21:01:13.404 6603-10712/? W/GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 18360000, Services 19056039, and Games 110770048
2019-09-05 21:01:13.560 15677-15677/? W/SignInActivity: onSignInFailed()...
2019-09-05 21:01:13.560 15677-15677/? W/SignInActivity: Sign in failed during 6
2019-09-05 21:01:13.560 15677-15677/? W/SignInActivity: ==> Returning non-OK result: 10002
2019-09-05 21:01:13.589 6603-10712/? W/GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 18360000, Services 19056039, and Games 110770048
```

And looking at the doc:

> The attempt to sign in to the Games service failed. For example, this
>   might happen if the network is flaky, or the user's account has been
>   disabled, or consent could not be obtained.

Full logs available [here](https://forums.coronalabs.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=8476).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new app in my Google Play Console and rebuilt my app with a new key and it works now.

Not sure what was wrong because I followed the same steps as the tutorial, maybe not in the exact same order this time...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Corona's default debug keystore by any chance?

This error typically occurs because the keystore that you are using is not the same that you've associated with your app in Google Play's developer console. In order to use Google Play Game Services in your app, or to even test them, you **must** build your app using a keystore that you've created for that specific game.

You can find more information here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling

Comment: No I'm not. I've created my own key following the guide on Corona's website: https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/androidBuild/index.html#signrelease
Is there a way to check (again) what keystore was used in the first place in Google Play's developer console?